# Angular set slide in panel with routing

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf3pip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I'm trying to set this slide-in panel with routing in Angular 2+, this code works fine in a flat html but i need  to trigger the panel with Angular routing, so if i go to the route: 'slideinpanel' the panel should open. What i've been trying is to trigger the panel when the slideinpanel component is loaded. The code is in the stackblitz link. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your routing app in this app add new route blank. this route charge by default when your load your app
{

    path: '',
    component: FirstComponentLoad
  },
{    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'slideinpanel',
    component: SlideInPanelComponent
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the ngAfterInit in the sidepanle component to load the function that showing the panel :

```
      export class SlideInPanelComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
setTimeout(this.slideInPanelFunction, 50);
      }
}
```

then in the function call the addClass function when you call the function

```
  slideInPanelFunction() {
    debugger;
    var panelTriggers = document.getElementsByClassName('js-cd-panel-trigger');
    if (panelTriggers.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < panelTriggers.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          var panelClass =
              'js-cd-panel-' + panelTriggers[i].getAttribute('data-panel'),
            panel = document.getElementsByClassName(panelClass)[0];
          // open panel when clicking on trigger btn
         addClass(panel, 'cd-panel--is-visible'); 
        //  panelTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         //   event.preventDefault();
        //    addClass(panel, 'cd-panel--is-visible');
      //    });
          //close panel when clicking on 'x' or outside the panel
          panel.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (
              hasClass(event.target, 'js-cd-close') ||
              hasClass(event.target, panelClass)
            ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              removeClass(panel, 'cd-panel--is-visible');
              console.log(i);
            }
          });
        })(i);
      }
    }

    //class manipulations - needed if classList is not supported
    //https://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/
    function hasClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList) return el.classList.contains(className);
      else
        return !!el.className.match(
          new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
        );
    }
    function addClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList) el.classList.add(className);
      else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += ' ' + className;
    }
    function removeClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(className);
      else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
        el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ');
      }
    }
  }
```

then you can handle the close function to route to the hello component

see the updated i made
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ncbylz

Comment: something is wrong with the panel animation, thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome, I added a delay for 50 ms to show the animation, see the updated one :). you can modify all the code and get rid of the JS code with a TS code

Comment: Thanks! the problem i'm facing right now is to get rid of the 'slideinpanelcomponent' in the URL when i close the panel

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to your router events from app component and subscribe to router `NavigationEnd` event

**App.component.ts**

First import the required

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/dist/types';
```

On the constructor inject the `Router` instance

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Then implement `ngOnInit` like the following:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events
    .pipe(filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe((event:NavigationEnd)=>{
        console.log("NavigationEnd to url",event.url)
        if(event.url=="/slideinpanel")
        {
          //Logic Goes here          
        }
    });
  }
```

You may need to unsubscribe from the router event on component destroy.

Answer (score 0):

if you want create slide with route /slidepanel you need create new component

`ng g -c slidepanel`

add you component on module.app if you use route app file add new route /slidepanel

in this component do you need add all styles html neccesary for run you slide.
check stylesheet file and name.component.ts remember visit

TypeScript: Typed JavaScript at Any Scale.https://www.typescriptlang.org

For more info Angular doc visit  https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks